# Help me debug this chunk of code which has no compilation errors but is not working as expected

Tags: java

I am coding this Sudoku Solver with the following algorithm:

Given a grid which is assumed to be a valid sudoku puzzle and exists at least 1 solution, it'll find the first solution and return it.

The puzzle is stored in a 2D array representing 9x9 slots.

If a solution does not exist, it returns a puzzle where puzzle[0][0] = 0, else all slots in the puzzle is supposedly filled up with values (1-9).

The algorithm is a bruteforce recursive method:

1. It searches the puzzle row by row for a single slot.
2. The method `possibleValuesInGrid()` returns the possible values that can fit into the slot based on the current puzzle and its existing values.
3. If there are no possible values to be placed in the slot, it returns a False (puzzle[0][0] = 0)
4. ELSE, it pops one of the values from the `LinkedList` of possible values and insert into the slot, and recursively call the same method again till all the slots are filled up.

---

The code is being hosted at pastebin so I don't flood this page. I suspect there might be a logic error somewhere although its a bruteforce method, or even a bug that I can't seem to figure.

I have hardcoded some system printlines to read through to figure for logic error, however I couldn't figure out where.

Also, how it stopped at [8][4] is also curious.

- [utils/PuzzleSolverBruteForce.java](http://pastebin.com/fa6227fe)
- [utils/PuzzleGenerator.java](http://pastebin.com/f36b89afe) (not completed, but the dependency part for BruteForce class is done in here, and completed)
- [runtime printlines for logic debugging](http://pastebin.com/f6adb45a0).

Comment: If it isn't working as expected, it clearly has an error somewhere.

Comment: First step: convert those while loops into more conventional for loops...

Comment: I recommend breaking the algorithm up into independently testable sub-steps and using JUnit or similar to test each one.

Comment: @all downvoters: it's a great educational value for all new users when you post a comment justifying your downvote.

Comment: @quosoo, didn't downvote this one. Looks like several people have a case of the Mondays.

Comment: wow, is everyone downvoting this because they can't solve this? i already broke this down as much as i can. please read the pastebin before even commenting.

Comment: @jonskeet, been using while loops because of its flexibility since coding in php/python/C. and that clearly is not an error.

Comment: why downvote??? that's a reasonable question. he posted all the source code and gives a clear description of how it is currently running and what goes wrong. indeed i think he took some time to think about how to phrase this question. +1 from me.

Comment: @Atmocreations: Really? Tell me what goes wrong?

Comment: @OscarReyes: Did you even read? Expected output is wrong. The log shows that the looping stops at 8,4 instead of 8,8, and I have been trying to figure out why that is but I can't.

Recursively it works, hence the log. I even tested possibleValuesInGrid() and it works as expected. Something is wrong and I can't pinpoint it, hence I posted this. If you did not even try helping, please bugger off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code fails because you are using clone on a multi-dimensional array (line 44). A clone only give you a shallow copy and in the case of a 2-dimensional array, that's not good enough. You need System.arraycopy(), but on each row, so call something like

```
public void 2dArrayCopy(int[][] source,int[][] target) {
    for (int a=0; a<source.length; a++) {
        System.arraycopy(source[a],0,target[a],0,source[a].length);
    }
}
```

You can see the symptom of your failed clone on your log on line 49, where the code suddenly sees a puzzle with an empty slot at 0:0.